# How to assign value in Django Templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have writing a template tag and take it to the templates:

```
{% check_somethings value1 value2 as is_checked %}
{% if is_checked %}
    # do it
{% endif %}
```

But there are some errors. I am doing so right?

```
check_somethings takes 2 arguments
```

There are:

```
@register.simple_tag
def check_somethings(value1, value2):
    if Mymodel.objects.filter(f1=value1, f2=value2):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Please add your templatetag implementation and the error you get.

Comment: Can you post the code for the tag itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "as something" pattern is not built in to Django tags, your tag has to explicitly provide that functionality, which you can't do with simpletag. You'll have to write a full Node and parser function, which is harder than it ought to be; but you can look at examples of built-in tags.

Answer (score 1):

Template tag parsing is very low level.  You have passed your template tag four arguments: `value1`, `value2`, `as`, and `is_checked`.  I'm not sure how to do what you want.  I'd check the code of tags that already do it, and compare.  I'm pretty sure @simpletag isn't going to cover it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [smart if tag](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1350/). Apparently it will be built in to 1.2.

Comment: In developing version of Django, it has added things like this.